# Multipart/form-data with additional parameters in .net

Tags: c#, .net, post

What is the best way to create post request like this one in .net ? 
I try to use HttpClient and MultipartFormDataContent classes but so far I can only be able to upload image. How can i add additional parameter like api key?

```
  POST /services/upload/ HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7d44e178b0434
    Host: api.flickr.com
    Content-Length: 35261

    -----------------------------7d44e178b0434
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="api_key"

    3632623532453245
    -----------------------------7d44e178b0434
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="auth_token"

    436436545
    -----------------------------7d44e178b0434
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="api_sig"

    43732850932746573245
    -----------------------------7d44e178b0434
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="C:\test.jpg"
    Content-Type: image/jpeg

    {RAW JFIF DATA}
    -----------------------------7d44e178b0434--
```

Answer (score -1):

Something along the lines of.. in C# + .NET 4.0

```
Uri uri =  new Uri("api.flickr.com");
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "POST";

//goes into the body. not header
NameValueCollection queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
queryString["api_key"] = "7d44e178b0434";
...

object returnValue = null;
 try
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(queryString);
                }

                returnValue = request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               ..
            }
```

And if you wanted to add something to the header -

```
 request.Headers.Add("HeaderKEY", somevalue);
```